# What is internal state?

Tags: c++, oop

What is this "internal state" people talk about all the time precisely? The term really irritates me. The internet couldn't provide me with a definition yet.

Comment: I guess it is that part of an object's state that is not externally visible, that is you cannot see it by querying the object.

Answer (score 3):

From [Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805353402)

> The state of an object encompasses all of the (usually static)
> properties of the object plus the current (usually dynamic) values of
> each of these properties

In object oriented programming the objects can have state (data) and behavior (function).

The behavior specifies what the object can do, and it is usually conditioned by its state.

The state can be represented by any member or static variable, and it will depend of the definition of the class the object is instance of.

**Update:** The ***internal*** state refers to those private variables that affect the behavior of the object but are not visible from the outside world.

For example, let's say you have an HTTP client having the following interface:

```
class HttpClient {
public:
  HttpClient(std::string host);
  HttpResponse get(std::string path);
  HttpResponse post(std::string path);
};
```

This object might have a getter for `host` but none for the current connection state.

A good optimization might be to keep the connection alive between requests (assuming the server allows it) so, in the first call to `get` or `post` the object will have to establish the connection and save the socket description in some internal variable that is not exposed to the user. The next time `get` or `post` is called the connection is already established (and the user has no idea).

In this case, the connection is part of the *internal state* of the object.

Comment: So this covers state .. what about "internal" state? Is that different?

Comment: The way I see it `a` and `b` "conform" the state of the instances of `some_class`, and, in an OOP world, *internal state* and *state* should be the same.

Comment: @user2864740 "Internal" state is the counterpart of "external" state. External state is state visible from outside the object. Internal state, therefore, is state visible only from within the object.

Answer (score 1):

What is your internal state?

Hungry, Thirst,

Put some variables on that.

So in OO terms.

My state is

drinks-requirement: two glass of water,
   food-requirement: sandwich

So the same concept applies in terms of an object. The sum total of the variables of anobject

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what @AdamBurry said, think of an object as a black box that another piece of code can use. That code instantiates it:

```
Order o = new Order();
```

Then the code asks for the object to modify itself:

```
OrderItem oi = new OrderItem("Widget", 5.5);
o.AddItemToOrder(oi);
```

Then the code asks for the object to do something.

```
o.GetTotal();
```

How is the order computing the new total, given the item that just got added? Does it have a list of `OrderItems`, complete with prices? You bet. It has internal details that the code calling into may have no way of getting to. Those black-boxy details that the object needs to very carefully keep track of are the internal state of the object.

A much more practical example of something you may never want to expose to the "outside" world are variables which maintain the "dirty" state of an object. Has it been modified, but not committed to the database, yet? External code should never need to know this, but the object may need to.

What about an object that lets you step forward or backward through a list? Somewhere in that object, there's going to be an internal state variable that acts as a pointer to the current record. Again, the calling code would never need to see this, but when the code calls the `.MoveNext()` method, the object is going to have to increment that pointer by one to maintain the state of where it is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The internal state of an object is the set of all its attributes' values. One particular aspect of the internal state is that a method applied to the object being in a defined internal state (= a specific set of all its attributes' value) will result in another, also defined (and reproducible) internal state.

This aspect is important when you somehow record system states that you want to replay afterwards in a simulation of the recorded system. By recording the original internal state of an object you are able to reproduce all its subsequent internal states by simply calling its methods without having to store any additional data. However this is easier said than done in practice...

Applied to C++ the internal state will not be altered by a `const` method.

A `mutable` attribute (= attribute modifiable by a `const` method) can be altered without semantically affecting the internal state of an object. At least this is the contract the developer goes for when he uses this modifier...